# Replace toothbrush every 3 to 4 months

Tags: dentistry, cleaning

I read from this link (http://www.ada.org/1887.aspx)

It says to:

> Replace toothbrushes at least every 3–4 months. The bristles become frayed and worn with use and cleaning effectiveness will decrease. Toothbrushes will wear out more rapidly depending on factors unique to each patient. Check brushes often for this type of wear and replace them more frequently if needed. Children’s toothbrushes often need replacing more frequently than adult brushes.

I had a question was that is this replacement require if the bristles were not frayed and worn even after 6 months of usage? Or are there scientific evidence showing that it is a must to replace the tooth brush every 3 to 4 months?

Comment: '3-4 months' is a very general term. Does it involve using a brush 2 or maybe 3+ times a day? Brushing for 2 or 10 minutes at a time? I would always think that disinfecting a brush is a more important issue. Whether you use UV light, boiling water or freezing, after a few months the brush doesn't look shiny anymore and it just makes more sense to get a new one.

Comment: -1 Who claims this is always true? It's a guideline and likely based on recommended usage. In the two extremes-never using it and literal constant use-it obviously breaks down. Clearly that breakdown is somewhere between the extremes and normal use.

Comment: hmm, after less than that a toothbrush no longer tends to look like something you'd want to stick in your mouth...

Comment: I generally use power toothbrushes, and chuck them when they stop running .. which is in the 3ish month timeframe